# Dell XPS 13 9310 2-in-1 drivers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, xps

I received this laptop with Windows 10 pre-installed. I set up dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu 20.04. Everything seems to be working well in Windows, no issues so far. Much is also working well in Ubuntu (eg display, mouse, keyboard, touchpad, wireless network, bluetooth, usb ports), but there are some problems:

1. The touchscreen is not responding to any touching.
2. The Dell Active Pen (PN579X) connects successfully via Bluetooth, but does not interact with the screen.
3. There is access to the USB ports on the Dell Performance Dock (WD19DC), but the two (not new) Dell displays (P2317H) are not detected.

The machine has 11th Generation Intel Core i7-1165G7 Processor and Intel Iris Xe Graphics. I booted Windows and ran Dell Update to update the BIOS. The Setting's About page says "Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)".

Don't know if the three issues are somehow related. Spent a lot of time searching the web for clues. Dell ships this laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 pre-installed in North America, but not in my region (Australia). Looking at Dell's US site, there are no specific drivers to download for Ubuntu.

Comment: Problem solved: Installing Ubuntu 20.10 fixed all issues mentioned!

Comment: I have exactly the same machine, and the touch screen worked out of the box on Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 LTS. However, coming out of hibernation didn't; the screen continued in black even though the keyboard lit up. The pen didn't work either.

Solved the hibernation problem by just installing laptop-mode-tools. Tried to solve the pen-problem by upgrading to 20.10 as per your post above. The pen still isn't working. Moreover, when I try to use it, the touch screen stops working. So I am wondering; do you have anything else installed that may be relevant to get this working? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing special installed. But after upgrading to Linux kernel 5.8.0-45-generic a few days ago, I lost the pen again. So I will boot 5.8.0-44-generic for a while...